# How to draw diagonal edges in Graphviz

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

How can I draw diagonal lines between two nodes in Graphviz (Dot Language).

I want to draw the following shape.

[image]

I tried:

```
graph G {
V[pos="0,0"];
N[pos="40,40!"];
V -- N [label="NSUBJ"]   
}
```

But it draws orthogonal lines. besides I want to draw multiple subgraphs with an order number as above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use `pos` attribute, but in that case you'd have to use `neato` and set `pos` for every node:

```
graph G {
    V [pos = "0,100"]
    N [pos = "50,0"]

    S [pos = "200,100"]
    VPC [pos = "150,0"]
    NPC [pos = "250,0"]

    V -- N [label="NSUBJ"]

    S -- VPC
    S -- NPC
}
```

Then use the following:

```
neato -n -Tpng -o test.png test.gv
```

The output is the following:

[image: neato with pos]

Also it's possible to make lines diagonal if use invisible nodes:

```
graph G {

    node [shape=plaintext]
    labelloc="b"
    pencolor=transparent

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        label="(1)"

        S_1 [label="S"]
        VPC_1 [label="VPC"]
        NPC_1 [label="NPC"]

        V_1 [label="V"]
        invis_1 [style=invis]
        N_1 [label="N"]

        V_1 -- invis_1 [style=invis]
        V_1 -- N_1 [label="NSUBJ"]

        S_1 -- VPC_1
        S_1 -- NPC_1
    }

    subgraph cluster_2 {
        label="(2)"

        VPC_2 [label="VPC"]
        V_2_2 [label="V"]
        NPC_2 [label="NPC"]

        V_2 [label="V"]
        invis_2 [style=invis]
        N_2 [label="N"]

        V_2 -- invis_2 [style=invis]
        V_2 -- N_2 [label="COPCOMP"]

        VPC_2 -- V_2_2
        VPC_2 -- NPC_2
    }
}
```

Running this sequence of commands produces the following output:

`ccomps -Cx test.gv | dot | gvpack -array_1 | neato -n2 -Tpng > test.png`

[image: graph output]